# Why Django test with blank data post does not work?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'd like to understand why this testing case does not work: I'm testing that my signup form in my view returns errors when I try to submit an empty form.

In tests.py:

```
class SignupViewTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_signup_post_blank(self):
        resp = self.client.post(reverse(signup), {}) # blank data dictionary
        self.assertFormError(resp, form='signup_form', field='email',
            errors='Ce champ est obligatoire') # French version of "This field is mandatory"
```

In views.py:

```
def signup(request):

    signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

    if signup_form.is_valid():
        ema = signup_form.cleaned_data['email']
        raw_pwd = signup_form.cleaned_data['password']

        try:
            BizProfile.create(ema, raw_pwd)
        except IntegrityError:
            signup_form.errors['__all__'] = signup_form.error_class([
                ERR_USER_EXISTS])
        else:
            messages.success(request, SUC_ACC_CREA)
            messages.info(request, INF_CONN)
            return redirect(signin)

    return render(request, 'sign_up.html', locals())
```

When testing manually in my browser, I can see there IS actually an error on the email field when I submit it without data.

But test result says:
`AssertionError: The field 'email' on form 'signup_form' in context 0 contains no errors`

Any idea of what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: What does your view.py code look like for the post?

Comment: why is there 'or None' in signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST or None)

Comment: @Camron_Godbout Kinda hack/shortcut used in Django forms (https://gist.github.com/pylemon/2330177). Don't think the problem is not related to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the problem *is* related to the `or None`.

That's because an empty dictionary is false. In an "or" condition, Python always returns the second value if the first is false. That means your form is being instantiated just with "None", rather than an empty dictionary: which means it is not being bound at all. A non-bound form does not have any errors.

Changing your test is not a good solution, because a browser would never submit the "email" key without a value: fields without values are simply not send in the POST data, which is why an empty dictionary is the right way to test this. Instead of changing your test, you should use the canonical view pattern, and remove that broken shortcut.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    if signup_form.is_valid():
        ...
else:
    signup_form = SignupForm()
return...
```

Comment: You're right... I was so happy when I found this shortcut (here actually) and asked myself "Why id this not in the Django doc?" I understand why now.